# Contaminated normal distribution, sample mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let's say I have contaminated normal distribution
\begin{align*}
    P_{\gamma}=(1-\epsilon)N(0,1) + \epsilon N(\gamma, 1): |\gamma| < C, \ \ \epsilon \in (0,1)
\end{align*}
and I would like to compute expected value of sample mean $\bar x^2$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb E_{P_{\gamma}}(\bar x^2)
\end{align*}
Can I just treat it as a mixed distribution, so that my random variable from this distribution follows $N(\gamma\epsilon, (1-\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^2)$ thus $\bar x \sim N(\gamma \epsilon, \frac{(1-\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^2}{n})$? It would give
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\bar x)=&\frac{(1-\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^2}{n}\\
[\Bbb E\bar x]^2=&\gamma^2\epsilon^2
\end{align}
then

\begin{align}
\Bbb E\bar x^2=\text{Var}(\bar x)+[\Bbb E\bar x]^2 = \frac{(1-\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^2}{n}+\gamma^2\epsilon^2
\end{align}

Am I correct?

Comment: Unless you are abusing notation, the law $P_\gamma$ is that of a random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb E[f(X)]=(1-\varepsilon)\mathbb E[f(N)]+\varepsilon\mathbb E[f(N_\gamma)]$, where $N\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ and $N_\gamma\sim\mathcal N(\gamma,1)$. So $\mathbb E[X]=\gamma\varepsilon$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X)=1+\gamma^2\varepsilon(1-\varepsilon)$. It is not true that $P_\gamma$ is a normal distribution.

Comment: @nejimban thanks! how did you compute expectancy and variance? could you please tell me?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$ above, and use that $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2$.

Comment: @nejimban but then I have to compute $\int x^2f(x)dx$ which is not that easy, especially for a non-zero shift. Can I use the fact that $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) \Rightarrow Y= \left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$?

Comment: @nejimban ok, I have it. But if now I want to obtain variance of the sample **mean**, how do I know that my observations ale uncorrelated, so that I can use the fact that variance of sum is the sum of variances?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551315/contaminated-normal-distribution-sample-mean